# Getting 0 As Status

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, http

I have a simple HTML file, that gets data from the server and outputs it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        function startRequest() {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://new-host-2.home/test.html", true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
        function handleStateChange() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert("The server replied with: ", xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    alert(xmlhttp.status);
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Woooo" onclick="startRequest()"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The file that is on the server, test.html looks like this:

```
<h1>Data received!</h1>
```

I keep getting 0 as a status, despite the fact that in the console, it says everything is fine, and gives a 200 status. When I change `if (xmlhttp.status == 200)` to `if (xmlhttp.status == 0)`, it just outputs `The server replied with:`. Why is this? Am I messing something up?
**EDIT**: It might just be my server, I'm gonna switch to a different one.
The Headers might be helpful:

```
Response Headers
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  13
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Sat, 09 Jun 2012 14:17:11 GMT
Etag    "267749b-d-4c20a6d0ef180"
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Last-Modified   Sat, 09 Jun 2012 13:52:22 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) DAV/2
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    new-host-2.home
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
```

Comment: As a side note, are you sure `alert` takes multiple arguments?

Comment: is the page you calling this from also on `http://new-host-2.home` ?

Comment: have you tried reading state from the instance passed via event object (as opposed to global var)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alert function only takes one parameter, you're passing 2.

Give this a shot:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
function startRequest() { 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                alert("The server replied with: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            else
                alert(xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://new-host-2.home/test.html", true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

If it still doesn't work, it might be a security issue:  http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/282972/why-am-i-getting-xmlhttprequest.status0

If it works in Safari, then try removing the domain in your request to make the path relative.  Firefox might be thinking that you're attempting some cross-domain stuff.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
function startRequest() { 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                alert("The server replied with: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            else
                alert(xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/test.html", true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: @BobbyTables - umm... OK.  Can you elaborate?  What happens when you open a browser and go to http://new-host-2.home/test.html  Is anything returned?

Comment: I click the input button, and nothing happens. When I put in an else block, it says that xmlhttp.status is 0

Comment: Why skip the `else` part? It won't fire multiple times with a `readyState` of `4`.

Comment: @BobbyTables - what happens when you go directly to the page with a browser?  What is returned?

Comment: What you'd think is returned, just a big header that says Hey!

Comment: @BobbyTables - the headers say you're using firefox. Try the same thing with Internet Explorer if you can.  Read this article: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/282972/why-am-i-getting-xmlhttprequest.status0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12337/discussion-between-chris-gessler-and-bobby-tables)

Comment: If anything, this should totally work in FF. If it doesn't, then there is not much point trying anything else.

Comment: @IliaG - Read the article I posted, FF has some cross-site security checks, where Safari and IE don't.  It may prove helpful to know if the same code works in another browser where it fails in FF.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to say what exactly is the issue here. Here are something things I suspect it might be

1) Same host policy. Make sure the page you are requesting it from is on the **exact** same host. For instance one could be `www.` and other one not. Simplest way to do it is to omit the host part of the URL when making the AJAX request.
`xmlhttp.open("GET", "/test.html");` should just work.

2) Scoping issues. Perhaps you are reading state from a different object than the one making the request? Make sure you are reading the same object by getting it from the event passed to the callback. Btw `XMLHttpRequest` is not reusable anyway, so don't think you are saving some resources by making it global. Much easier to declare it inside the `startRequest` function.
Then change callback like this:

```
function handleStateChange(e)
{
    var xmlhttp = e.target;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert("The server replied with: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        else
            alert(xmlhttp.status);
    }
}
```

There are some very nice wrappers for making AJAX requests (jQuery in particular), but if you are bent on making your own (or just learning insides), then this is approx what you want:

```
function startRequest(url, callback)
{
    var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e)
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300)
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

startRequest("/test.html", function(response) {alert("The server replied with: " + response);});
```